# how to set up aws cognito for the following rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have this req

Admin: manages the user access to website and gives them the rights as a content manager.

Content manager: These users can use the website to search, create content and change the setting for the content in the website.

I set up user pool in Cognito gave the callback url so when I successfully login it redirects to the page That I provided.

I can't understand what it means to set up roles
I know groups with AWS roles like for access to s3 ,dynamo etc...
is this wrong requirement or it's possible to do?

Comment: What you are looking for is to make roles in your application. In this case, it doesn't have anything to do with AWS roles... You can use groups from Cognito and then in your application code you can check which group the user belongs to and give him appropriate permissions.

Comment: ok thanks a lot ,you made it clear for me .https://stackoverflow.com/users/1992773/caldazar